# turn off all css3

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a lot of CSS3 and I want to have 2 css versions: one with all the css3 and one without. I know I could simply remove the declarations but I'm wondering if there's another way to disable them. Specifically, I want to disable text-shadow, box-shadow and border-radius.

Thanks.

Comment: i think using two css is the better idea :)

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? You should use graceful degradation / progressive enhancement.

Comment: under what circumstances do you want to disable these things?

Comment: If you want to see what your browser looks like in archaic browsers, it might be simpler to just use an archaic browser.

Comment: @all: the site I'm building uses a lot of CSS3. It also works in IE8, but of course everything looks a bit more "squarish". However, it doesn't look bad at all and I want to give users the option to switch to this look and feel.

Comment: @frenchie why would any user who can see all your nice CSS3 effects ever want to see what it looks like without them? why would they care?

Comment: So you're actually just trying to create two different CSS themes?

Comment: @Jason: you give people options to play with backgrounds and some will spends hours engaging in tuning backgrounds. I want users to feel like they're building theirr own look and feel.

Comment: @frenchie thats the point I mean, if you wanna give your users multiple look and feel options than why don't you use different CSS's? load it dynamically as per cookies value set by user..

Comment: @SLaks: yes, but I also want people to be able to switch CSS3 oon/off.

Comment: @SLaks: people love the feeling of customizing things. And people buy feelings...

Comment: @SLaks: see below for my one-line solution. Now I can't stop playing with the CSS3 style switcher functionality!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable them, all you can do is override the styles using CSS:

```
body * {
   text-shadow:none;
   ...etc...
}
```

(Hey, I never said it's a good idea to do this, but it will work)

***Edit: This answer got me on the right track; thanks. Here's the solution:***

create a class called NoCSS3 defined like this:

```
.NoCSS3 * {
    text-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;}
```

And then in javascript, you add this line:

```
$('body').addClass('NoCSS3');
```

And you're done!

Comment: together with `!important`, this is surely the favourite solution.

Comment: horrible, absolutely horrible. !important is the last resort.

Comment: I prefer CSS3 pie to solve me CSS3 problems the other way around. Yup, !important usually means you need to refactor your CSS.

Comment: @frenchie: [This article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) covers it very well. You will need it to reset the css3 attributes even for selectors with a higher specificity - that's what it's made for.

Comment: I created a class NoCSS3 with {text-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;border-radius:0px;} I'm adding this line $(body).addClass('NoCSS3'); in the doc.ready function but it's not working.

Comment: Try `$("body")` instead... Your `body` is an undefined variable.

Comment: css for this: body.noCSS3 * {...}

Comment: thinkinng about it, this kind of crazy situation is exactly what important is needed for, I take it back! :D

Comment: @Bergi: yes, that solved the syntax error. But still not the problem

Comment: @Bergi: ok, I can see that every element on the page now has the .noCSS3 class. However, it seems that the definitions of each element's CSS take precedence over the global .noCSS3 * {... definition.

Comment: ok, I got it to work: I'm editing this answer to combine it all.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a bookmarklet called **[deCSS3](http://davatron5000.github.com/deCSS3/)**

It toggles off all your css3 features (okay not "all", [a whitelist of supported CSS3 features is documented here](https://github.com/davatron5000/deCSS3#readme). If you like, you can also toggle CSS3 back on.

As a bonus: if you're using Modernizr, it flips off those values as well, so your `.no-boxshadow` classes get picked up.

To people wondering why you'd want to do this.. this workflow is very nice so you can develop totally in Chrome, but quickly look at what your lo-fi version (that you'll serve to IE7, IE8) will look like.

Here's a before and after with using deCSS3:

[image]

Comment: Not complete, though. Try `<input type='number'>`, in chrome. Or see the way that inputs get styled in chrome, on focus. These things would not change by using deCSS3.

Comment: Is there a one-two liner version??

Comment: See the one-liner solution I posted on the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into **CSS modernizer** feature offered by [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/).

Can be used for many other features as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to have a look at [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) ? This is a javascript library for detecting what is available on the client side, and behaving accordingly. Looks like what you are looking for.
You can find a good introduction to it [here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/04/an-introduction-to-modernizr-for-designers/)

Comment: I disagree. This answer would be good, but does not match his question, because he is not looking for progressive enhancement.

Comment: I've written my site without a single plug-in; I want to keep my site plug-in free! The only dependency is jquery.